# How to add google custom search in our website

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a search box which simply redirect the user to the official google website with a special dork, for example: `site:www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the search engine and then you can integrate it to your own site.

Follow this link

https://moz.com/ugc/how-to-put-google-custom-site-search-into-your-current-website-design